# Android X86 Gingerbread with Ethernet

Tags: android, linux, terminal, android-x86, live-cd

I am using android x86 gingerbread live cd, when i am tring to give ip address by
<kbd>Alt + F1</kbd>

```
su ifconfig "ip address" eth0 up
```

Its showing

> `SIOCSIFADDR(no such device)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution,If you are tring to configure ethernet to get internet the you need to follow following steps in android-x86 froyo:
`1.<kbd>Alt + F1 </kbd>`
`2.ifconfig eth0 "Ip address" netmask "255.255.255.0"`
`3.route add default gw "default gateway" dev eth0`
`4.setprop net.dns "dns server"`
`5.setprop net.gprs.http-proxy http://"proxy address"`

Answer (score 0):

The x86 live cd does currently not support wired networks.

See the [changelog](http://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-4-0-rc1):

> Known issues
>
> Suspend and resume doesn't work on some targets.
>
> *No Ethernet support.*